# How to re-run jest failed test suite

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, jestjs

I want to re-run the whole test suite when any test has status failed. I only found how to re-run the test case but I want to re-run the whole test suite.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. I checked the Jest docs and see no options for this.

Answer (score 1):

The `jest` command gives an exit code 1 if a test failed, 0 if all tests succeeded.

You could create a bash shell script that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
jest

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "The tests succeeded"
  exit 0
else
  echo "The tests failed, running jest again"
  jest
fi
```

Reads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55927777/is-it-standard-for-jest-to-exit-with-a-status-1-if-any-test-fails
- https://shapeshed.com/unix-exit-codes/

Comment: Could be shortened to `$ jest || jest`